# How to set authentication model to allow cross-domain access?

Tags: web-services, security, cross-site

How do I change the security settings to allow cross-domain on the same web-server? 
I have multiple instance or site collections on the same server but want to make sure that web-services to list.asmx can be called from any of the sites on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a discussion on stackoverflow on this topic with an accepted answer:

> [Best way to handle Cross Domain on SharePoint Intranet w/o server side, silverlight, DBC etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879371/best-way-to-handle-cross-domain-on-sharepoint-intranet-w-o-server-side-silverli)

In a nutshell, you can use crossdomain.xml policy file, [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) or [jQuery.support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/).[cors](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) wrapper for browser capabilities or create a [server-side proxy](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Cross-Domain_Proxy) to work around the cross-domain restrictions.

Comment: Thanks I had come across JSONP in my research, thanks for the additional info and reference.

Answer (score 0):

The Lists web service is available from all SharePoint sites.

> To access this Web service set a Web reference to `http://<site>/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx.`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: This answer is really not on topic as there's an explicitly specified Cross-Domain nature of the question.

Comment: Perhaps the basis for the question is flawed. You do not need to go cross-domain to access Lists.asmx.

Comment: Well, if you use different web applications, whether port- or AAM/hostname based, or host-named site collections (vanity URLs), you do have to go cross-domain.